# Summarize all data from other tabs with same format and column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have customer sheets which i must summarize into a single tab so i use this query;

`=QUERY({'ROC155'!B2:AB;'ROC152'!B2:AB;'ROC135'!B2:AB;'ROC002'!B2:AB;'ROC009'!B2:AB;'ROC145'!B2:AB;'ROC048'!B2:AB;'ROC010'!B2:AB;'ROC157'!B2:AB;'ROC024'!B2:AB;'ROC064'!B2:AB;'ROC073'!B2:AB;'ROC160'!B2:AB;'ROC159'!B2:AB;'ROC084'!B2:AB;'ROC091'!B2:AB;'ROC035'!B2:AB;'ROC161'!B2:AB;'ROC042'!B2:AB;'ROC164'!B2:AB;'ROC049'!B2:AB;'ROC162'!B2:AB;'ROC004'!B2:AB;'ROC077'!B2:AB;'ROC165'!B2:AB;'ROC154'!B2:AB;TRV_REV!B2:AB;'ROC131-3'!B2:AB},"SELECT * where Col9 is not null",0)`

i must create new tab for new customer and must udpate the formula, so i use get sheets name using another script called **sheetnames()** so i can know what new tab that i have added.

and i use

`="{"&TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,B7:B)&"}"` to get this:

```
{'ROC155'!B2:AB;'ROC152'!B2:AB;'ROC135'!B2:AB;'ROC002'!B2:AB;'ROC009'!B2:AB;'ROC145'!B2:AB;'ROC048'!B2:AB;'ROC010'!B2:AB;'ROC157'!B2:AB;'ROC024'!B2:AB;'ROC064'!B2:AB;'ROC073'!B2:AB;'ROC160'!B2:AB;'ROC159'!B2:AB;'ROC084'!B2:AB;'ROC091'!B2:AB;'ROC035'!B2:AB;'ROC161'!B2:AB;'ROC042'!B2:AB;'ROC164'!B2:AB;'ROC049'!B2:AB;'ROC162'!B2:AB;'ROC004'!B2:AB;'ROC077'!B2:AB;'ROC165'!B2:AB;'ROC154'!B2:AB;'TRV_REV'!B2:AB;'ROC131-3'!B2:AB}
```

How to replace those manual adding new range and tab to simple formula; because I try;

```
=QUERY("{"&TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,SHEETLIST!B7:B)&"}","SELECT * where Col9 is not null",0)
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks
Nico